# Determine when the user scrolled downed using the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've created an event to trigger whenever the user scrolls down using the mouse little wheel. But what happens in the user scrolls down by dragging down the scroll bar?

I would like to trigger the same event when he scrolls down by dragging the scrollbar down, as if he was scrolling down using the mouse wheel.

this is the way I'm handling things right now:

```
    var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" 
    $(window).bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){

        var evt = window.event || e
        evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;
        var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta


        if(delta > 0) {
            // some code in the future if it's up
        }
        else{
        // some code if it's down (would like this block of code to be executed
           when the user draggs down the scrollbar)
            }
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks ina advance!

Comment: Why don't you just bind it to `$(window).on('scroll')`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Dunno, I haven't used that since I couldn't find a way to determine whenever i scrolled down. But now I see a way how to do it thanks for minitech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding to icky browser-specific events, use `scroll`:

```
var lastScroll = 0;

$(window).on({
    scroll: function() {
         if(window.pageYOffset > lastScroll) {
             // Scrolling down
         }

         lastScroll = window.pageYOffset;
    }
});
```

(If you need IE<9 support, by the way, it’s `document.documentElement.scrollTop`.)

Comment: And what if he scrolled up to the top of the page and then back to the end of it? there is some range of scroll-down when it's not gonna detect that :o

Comment: Where should I inject this `document.documentElement.scrollTop` if i want the IE < 9 support?

Comment: @kfirba: No, it should detect that too. And you should do `var yOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;` and then `if(yOffset > lastScroll)` and `lastScroll = yOffset`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've just noticed that the assignment of `lastScroll` happens every time the user scrolls, regardless the if statement occurred or not.

Comment: you are aware this does not answer the question? What if he scrolls with a touch event on a touch screen? this is not a valid answer to the question imho

Comment: @Toskan: The question is: “I've created an event to trigger whenever the user scrolls down using the mouse little wheel. But what happens in the user scrolls down by dragging down the scroll bar?” Mobile devices have neither (and don’t treat scrolling in the same way at all, not even close). I don’t know what the use case is, but this detects what was asked. It may not be the same as your question.

Comment: no. Simply **no**. The question is: "But what happens in the user scrolls down by dragging down the scroll bar?

I would like to trigger the same event when he scrolls down by dragging the scrollbar down, as if he was scrolling down using the mouse wheel." Either fix the answer, or fix the question. This misleads people to this thread for nothing.

Comment: @Toskan: I quoted the question in my comment. You don’t have to quote it again, unless you wanted to place emphasis on the “using the mouse wheel” part… which this also works absolutely fine for. (Most) Mobile devices don’t even set `document.documentElement.scrollTop`, because they don’t actually scroll the document element. Please don’t blame me if you’ve found the wrong question for your needs; keep searching.